# how the changes will be present even after restart of container

Tags: docker

I have created a container after that i installed an apache2,curl,net-tools packages and started the apache2 service then i have stopped the container and again i started it but when i see the apache2 service status it was showing not running and other packages are in place. if the container is stopped means it should erase the changes which i made on writeable layer but in my case it didn't happen still the package is present on container writable layer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333957/why-my-docker-containers-writable-layer-persists-after-the-container-exits - in short this is expected behavior. Image is unmodified, container is modified and preserved.